# How is $\xi+2a\eta<0$ an "obvious necessary condition" for $y^3+2y^2(1-2a-\xi)+y(1-4\xi+8a\xi)-2\xi-4a\eta >0$ to be satisfied for positive $y$?

Tags: inequality, mathematical-physics, cubics, simple-functions

How is $$\xi+2\alpha\eta<0$$ an 'obvious necessary condition' for the inequality

$$y^3+2y^2(1-2\alpha-\xi)+y(1-4\xi+8\alpha\xi)-2\xi-4\alpha\eta >0$$
to be satisfied for positive $y$ (as claimed in [this passage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Br06.png) of an article)?

Someone please help me understand. I want to use the author's method, but I just don't see how the last coefficient affects the inequality.

Comment: Set $y=0$ (or converging to 0 if you insist on positive).

Comment: [Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34121/42969). Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. – For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the text says that the statement shall hold true for all positive $y$. If you let $y \to 0$ you get exactly the condition.

More formally, for some arbitrarily small $y = \epsilon > 0$ we have, to order $\cal{O}(\epsilon)$, that
$$y^3+2y^2(1-2\alpha-\xi)+y(1-4\xi+8\alpha\xi)-2\xi-4\alpha\eta \\
\to \epsilon(1-4\xi+8\alpha\xi)-2(\xi+2\alpha\eta) $$.

For this to remain positive, since the first term gets arbitrarily small, the second term needs to remain positive, which is the case if and only if $\xi+2\alpha\eta < 0$.

Comment: yes, all y is positive, but still, I need to discuss this, unfortunately, I'm a physics major, and don't fully understand this could you, reference more material for me to read on this

Comment: I made the answer more formal.